# Live render generic HTML code using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know of a way that I can live render HTML code on a page with form input.

For instance, this URL has a good example: https://buttons.cm/

The button text renders on-page and the same with the code as you type. - The button color is the only thing that doesn't change but in my case, I would also want the button color to change as well.

I'm already thinking that I need to capture input values with state and output them on-page but I'm not sure how to have the code render and also change based on what is put into the form.

I greatly appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some initial state for default values

```
state = {
 color: 'blue';
}
```

Then in your render wire it up in two places - the input and the displayed example

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="edit-controls">
        <input value={this.state.color} onChange={this.setColor} />
      </div>
      <div className="preview">
        <div style={{ color: this.state.color }}>
          {'The color of this text is ' + this.state.color}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then your setColor function (wired to the onChange of the input) updates the state

```
setColor = (e) => {
  this.setState({ color: e.target.value });      
}
```

---

To show/hide arbitrary HTML elements you can conditionally render markup based on state.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.FormCheckboxChecked && <MyCheckedComponent />}
      {!this.state.FormCheckboxChecked && <div>
        <div>Check the checkbox to see the cool stuff!</div>
      </div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

```js
class Editor extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttonUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif',
    buttonText: 'Example',
    buttonColor: 'burlywood',    
    color: 'blue'
  }
  
  setColor = (e) => {
    this.setState({ color: e.target.value });      
  }
  
  setButtonColor = (e) => {
    this.setState({ buttonColor: e.target.value });      
  }
  
  setButtonUrl = (e) => {
    this.setState({ buttonUrl: e.target.value });      
  }
  
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="editor">
        <div className="edit-controls">
          <div>
            <div>Text Color:</div>
            <input value={this.state.color} onChange={this.setColor} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>Button Color:</div>
            <input value={this.state.buttonColor} onChange={this.setButtonColor} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>Button Background:</div>
            <input value={this.state.buttonUrl} onChange={this.setButtonUrl} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="preview">
          <div style={{ color: this.state.color }}>
            {'The color of this text is ' + this.state.color}
          </div>          
          <button style={{ 
            color: this.state.buttonColor,
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.buttonUrl + ')'
          }}>
            {this.state.buttonText}
          </button>          
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Editor />,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.editor {
  display: flex;
}

.edit-controls {
  flex: 1;
}

.edit-controls>div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.preview {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, the button was just an example.

Let's say I want other HTML elements to change based on form input. Maybe even a section of a webpage.

How can I get that to render on-page after values are changed in a form? Essentially, the functionality would be similar to codepen but instead of a text editor taking input, it would be a form.

Comment: If the thing you want to change and the thing that causes the change are completely unrelated components it gets a little harder, you might want to look into redux for keeping a global state.  If it's just arbitrary markup you want to show based on what they select in your form (assuming the form is part of your component?) I can edit in a quick example of that.  I feel like I'm not quite understanding what you want though, apologies.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. - It should be one component. So exactly what is shown within this example here https://buttons.cm/ - but let's say it wasn't just a button. Let's say I also had some text and an image above that button that I also wanted changing while values were being added to the form. The part that I'm not fully grasping is how can I actually get the code to render on-page while values are changing in the form. It's easy to output the code, but I also want the visual render of the output. If that makes sense?

Comment: Here is another example that has similar functionality https://www.sendtric.com/

Comment: You are wanting to type markup into the text area (the yellow section from your link) and have it render as you type?

Comment: I want it to work just like the example on buttons.cm - I already know how to output the yellow section as it's just text. However, I also want to know how to render the button itself. For instance when you add an image url to the form, the button changes the background image. After a new image URL is provided you can see the change on the button itself.

Comment: Added a snippet to show what I was talking about initially, isn't that what you describe?  Mess with the inputs and you can see the things you type reflected in the markup ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I'm looking for! - Really appreciate your time and effort!  :)

Comment: Awesome! glad we got it figured out :)